# how to generate many pdf pages with mpdf1?

Tags: php, html, pdf

im usign mpdf1 and i need to print a pdf containing a table with 4000 rows .

how can I do this using mpdf1 ?

there is a way to avoid waiting several minutes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now mpdf 6.0 is available and it's stable. I have downloaded mpdf 6.0 and extracted in mpdf60 folder. Following code sample shows how to generate PDF with html table.

```
<?php
include_once ('mpdf60/mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetAuthor('StackOverflow');

$html = getLargeTableHtml();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf');

function getLargeTableHtml()
{
    $html = '<table border="1">';
    for($cou = 1; $cou <= 4000; $cou++) {
        $html .= '<tr><td>row - ' . $cou . '</td><td>' . md5(rand()) .'</td></tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';
    return $html;
}
```

If you want to send pdf response unblocked fashion, then there are few patterns.

1.) If large table does not have content changed with time (static data)

- Pre generate PDF.
- Keep a reference file name in a table.
- When user request PDF, send pre-generated PDF instead of generating it during request.

2.) If large table has dynamic content changed with time

- Queue PDF generation process.
- Save a reference file name in a table.
- Email user with download link after PDF generation process finished.

Comment: i've a dynamic content and in localhost my apache server is near to crash for the heavy processing....
i fear that online can give me some problems..

Answer (score 0):

you need to start  multitasking in PHP.

here is a nice example

http://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/